# Can not disable "default" suffix-rules, in Gnu-Make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

***My Makefile, looks like the following:***

```
.SUFFIXES:foo


# Disable "default" suffix-rules.
MAKEFLAGS=-r


# A rule without a recipe!
all.o::

# File 'all.c' is "ought to exist".
all.c:
    touch '$@'
```

***Executing, I get:***

```
# Gnu-make still applies the "default" suffix-rule '.c.o'. Wrong?
$ make
cc    -c -o all.o all.c
```

Why can I not disable the suffix rule?

Comment: `make -r`; it reads the default rules before it reads the makefile to find that it should not have read the default rules.

Comment: @Jonathan That is true only for old versions of Gnu-Make.
Modern versions allow the Makefile-level syntax too.

Comment: And now we need to define ancient and modern.  I last looked at this sort of issue in probably 1993, so it could be that ancient is very ancient.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  4.0 and up.

Comment: That's pretty new.  There are lots of systems still using 3.8x, for example.  Probably older releases but still in use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, but that was fixed in later versions.
Or so I thought. Because it works, sometimes! Sometimes, however, it doesn't. As evident above!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the addition of the `-r` flag only removes *default* suffix rule settings.  When you use `.SUFFIXES: foo` you're adding a new suffix rule to the existing settings.  After you do that, the value of `.SUFFIXES` is no longer the same as the default value and so adding the `-r` flag does not change it.  This could be considered a useful enhancement request if you wanted to file it on [Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make).

If you want to use new suffix rules but not any pre-defined ones, you can use the method that's been available forever and even required by the POSIX standard; first delete all the existing ones then add your new ones:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining a prerequisite to `.SUFFIXES` adds to the list of known suffixes. It does not remove the already known suffixes. As a kind of exception, if you define a rule for `.SUFFIXES` with no prerequisites, you cancel all implicit rules:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SUFFIXES:
foo.c:
    touch $@
$ rm -f foo.* ; make foo.o
make: *** No rule to make target `foo.o'.  Stop.
```

Note: to cancel only the implicit rule that makes `.o` from `.c` one can also add a pattern rule without recipe:

```
%.o: %.c
```

Concerning `MAKEFLAGS`, according the documentation, its primary use seems to be passing options to sub-makes. However, the documentation also states that:

*You can also set MAKEFLAGS in a makefile, to specify additional flags that should also be in effect for that makefile*

So, logically, defining `MAKEFLAGS = -r` in the makefile should have the same effect as invoquing `make -r`. This is the behaviour you expected. Apparently, this is not the case (with GNU make versions 3.81 and 3.82):

```
$ cat Makefile
MAKEFLAGS += -r
foo.c:
    touch $@
$ rm -f foo.* ; make --version ; make foo.o
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
touch foo.c
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

and:

```
$ rm -f foo.* ; make --version ; make foo.o
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
touch foo.c
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

But it works with GNU make 4.0 and 4.1:

```
$ rm -f foo.* ; make --version ; make foo.o
GNU Make 4.0
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.o'.  Stop.
```

and:

```
$ rm -f foo.* ; make --version ; make foo.o
GNU Make 4.1
Built for i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.o'.  Stop.
```

Apparently, the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not correct.
[.SUFFIXES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets)

Comment: Yes, you **could** do this or that etc. But, one options is: `MAKEFLAGS = -r`. Turns out, however, that it works only sometimes. Maybe.

Comment: The make documentation explains how `MAKEFLAGS` is used to pass options to sub-makes. It is its primary use. It also states that _You can also set MAKEFLAGS in a makefile, to specify additional flags that should also be in effect for that makefile_ but, you are right, this does not work with `-r`. Maybe something we should report as a documentation bug.?

Comment: Your bug report was "fixed" in 4.0. My question, however, showed that the "fix" still needs another fix.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently, the `.SUFFIXES` target, the `MAKEFLAGS` variable and the `all.o` target interact in strange ways. Depending whether you declare them or not (8 combinations, typing `make all.o` instead of `make` when the `all.o` target is not defined) you get either `all.o` built, `make: Nothing to be done for 'all.o'.` or `make: *** No rule to make target 'all.o'.  Stop.`